# bigtable.SampleRowKeys return a single key

Tags: go, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to write code that does a full table scan in go by using the bigtable.Table.SampleRowKeys RPC method. The table as around 7m rows (verified with cbt), yet the call returns a single key, whereas the documentation mention:

> // SampleRowKeys returns a sample of row keys in the table. The returned row keys will delimit contiguous sections of
> // the table of approximately equal size, which can be used to break up the data for distributed tasks like MapReduce.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that the code was tested with bigtable-emulator and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the returned keys are midpoints, thus if it returns a single key, say `[k1]`, then the ranges are `[("", k1), (k1, "")]`.